# Using JPA creates SQL Syntax Errors

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, eclipselink, persistence

I'm programming a simple Java program which accesses a database (MariaDB).

When running, I always run into an error which says *Table ... doesn't exist*.
This is the case because when JPA calls the CREATE TABLE statement it uses `NUMBER(n)` as a type for the fields in my class that are declared as an int. This causes a syntax error and the table will not be created. Due to that when trying to insert the new user into the db the error occurs. Replacing the `NUMBER` with `INT` or `DECIMAL` works fine.

I thought the MariaDB driver would take care of it.

The error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" jakarta.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.0.v202012081010): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=68) Table 'dbtest.user' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: INSERT INTO User (ID, eMail, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" jakarta.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.0.v202012081010): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=68) Table 'dbtest.user' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: INSERT INTO User (ID, eMail, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(db.models.User@1b9b0b25)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:163)
    at db.Connector.registerUser(Connector.java:15)
    at UI.Register_User$1.actionPerformed(Register_User.java:40)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.0.v202012081010): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=68) Table 'dbtest.user' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: INSERT INTO User (ID, eMail, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(db.models.User@1b9b0b25)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2045)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:912)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2984)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1826)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4329)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1496)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1586)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:138)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=68) Table 'dbtest.user' doesn't exist
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:62)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:153)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:274)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientSidePreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientSidePreparedStatement.java:229)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientSidePreparedStatement.execute(ClientSidePreparedStatement.java:149)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientSidePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientSidePreparedStatement.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:898)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException: Table 'dbtest.user' doesn't exist
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException.of(MariaDbSqlException.java:34)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.exceptionWithQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:194)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.exceptionWithQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:177)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:321)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientSidePreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientSidePreparedStatement.java:220)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'dbtest.user' doesn't exist
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1683)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1545)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1508)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:318)
    ... 72 more
```

The create statement:

```
Call: CREATE TABLE User (ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, eMail VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE, username VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE, password NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE User (ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, eMail VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE, username VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE, password NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))")
```

The User class:

```
package db.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 60, name = "username")
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "password")
    private int pass;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = "eMail")
    private String email;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name, int pass, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

The function causing the error:

```
    public boolean registerUser(User u) {
        if(em.contains(u))
            return false;
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(u);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer to Mark's comment, here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="mariadb-localhost">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>db.models.User</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/dbtest"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <!-- or just value="create-tables" -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: How do you create the table and how are you connecting to the db?

Comment: The error itself has nothing *directly* to do with `NUMBER` vs `INT`. The error simply means that the table you're inserting into **does not exist**. It might be the result of a failure to create tables, but you don't show that in your question anywhere (you just hint at that by mentioning `NUMBER` vs `INT`). As to that problem, that would suggest that you have configured EclipseLink incorrectly (e.g. it's using an Oracle dialect instead of a MariaDB/MySQL dialect).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I edited my question and put my persistence.xml at the bottom.

Comment: @Lorelorelore I connect to the db via Persistence if that is what you mean.

Comment: I have no experience with EclipseLink, but you may need to add the property `eclipselink.target-database` with value `MySQL`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel although I am using MariaDB?

Comment: Yes, because EclipseLink doesn't seem to have MariaDB support, but I expect (hope?) the MySQL dialect should be close enough given MariaDB was forked from MySQL.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried your suggestion and it did not work, because then JPA is unable to connect to the database. So I guess I need to continue using the mariadb Driver.

Comment: My suggestion is to **add** `<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>` to the `<properties>` element, not to switch drivers or anything.